# proper use of the array.push method

Tags: javascript

if I have a simple test function that adds even numbers to an array:

```
function isEven(n){
    var enumbers = [];
    if (n % 2 == 0){
        enumbers.push (n);
    }
}
```

how can I increment my parameter until I have a set number of members in my array? for instance, I've tried this:

```
function isEven(n){
    var enumbers = [];
    while ( enumbers.length < 10){
    if (n % 2 == 0){
        enumbers.push (n);
    }
    console.log (enumbers);
             n = n + 1;
    isEven(n);
    }
}
isEven(1);
```

but it seems to just create a new array for each number until it finally throws a range error (maximum call stack size exceeded).

Comment: Test against `enumbers.length`?

Comment: your calling `isEven` recursivly inside your loop. So for every function call you actually call your function 10 additional times.

Comment: that was a typo... i had already corrected that but I got the same result.

Comment: What is this function supposed to do?

Comment: keep evaluating numbers 1 through however many it takes to push a predetermined (in this case, 10) number of even numbers into the "enumbers" array.

Comment: if you call `isEven(1)` are you expecting an array of `2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20` ?

Comment: yes, that is exactly the array I'm expecting

Comment: oops I responded to the wrong programmer. I tried your code and got a strange result. It returned 3 identical arrays with 2 members [2,4]. Not sure whats going on there.

Comment: And then what? You're not returning anything from the function, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @DavidThomas if I understand your question correctly, I want to be able to apply the tactic to other equations and be able to call the arrays produced and manipulate them as desired.

Comment: @kjarsenal http://stackoverflow.com/a/17222959/938822 and test the jsfiddle links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question.
But you shouldn't use global variables, and it is unnecessary to call your function recursively inside a while loop.

The error `maximum call stack size exceeded` is your browser trying to break a infinity loop.

This is what you need.

Examples here [jsFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/2uwKG/) and [jsFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/3r28J/)

```
function isEven(n) {
    var enumbers = [];

    while (enumbers.length < 10) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            enumbers.push(n);
        }
        n++;
    }
    return enumbers;
}
```

Setup a test

```
var n = 1;
var evenArray = isEven(n); //call isEven function and it returns an array

document.body.innerHTML = evenArray; //2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20
```

Answer (score 2):

It's creating that array multiple times because you're constantly calling that function with:

```
isEven(n);
```

You're also not comparing to the length of the array, just the array. Add `.length` to `enumbers`. Try changing to:

```
var enumbers = [];
while ( enumbers.length < 10){
    if (n % 2 == 0){
        enumbers.push (n);
    }
    console.log (enumbers);
}
```

Comment: The strategy was to keep calling isEven until the array had ten members. That's why I put it in a while loop. I think I just need to know how to properly increment the function parameter isEven(?)

Comment: You don't need to keep calling that, because each time you do, it re-initializes the array. Your while loop is taking care of the atleast 10 numbers part.

Comment: @kjarsenal: Consider either calling a function that puts *one* number in the array repeatedly (recursively), or putting that functions' body in a loop. Not both.

Comment: Thank you Bergi and Vitim. I think I misunderstood the way the while loop operates. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that (enumber < 10) apparently always evaluates to true, causing an endless loop. But it is this comparison that is wrong, since you're comparing an integer with an array I think you're trying to get the array length?:

```
while (enumbers.length < 10) {
```

Another thing. enumbers is a local variable, so each call to isEven has it's own array. Therefore, the functions is called recursively, over and over again.

Comment: That is now fixed. However, try `[0,2,4] < 10`…

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create the array outside of is even method

Answer (score -1):

I would have written something like:

```
function isEven(n,enumbers){  
    while(enumbers < 10){  
        if (n % 2 == 0){  
             enumbers.push (n);  
        }
        console.log (enumbers);  
        n = n + 1;  
        isEven(n, enumbers);  
    }  
}  
var enumbers = [];  
isEven(1,enumbers);
```

Comment: this actually is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. You just copied my codebase before I remembered to add .length to enumbers. this is great

Comment: Please either use recursion *or* a while-loop